# Setting up video streaming for JWPlayer

Tags: iis-7, video-streaming, iis-7.5, jwplayer

What's the quickest and easiest way for me to enable video streaming on IIS 7.5 (Win2K8 R2). I will use ffmpeg to convert the videos to whatever format they need to be in, and I'm planning to use the JWPlayer to play them. The videos need to HTML5 compatible so they can be viewed on iphone & ipad.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any special streaming solution for HTML5, but for Flash you would need to implement a pseudo streaming module on your web server. Here is some more information - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to setup pseudo streaming for H.264 video in order to prevent loading the entire video. Am I misunderstanding something (I am kinda new in the world of video development).

Comment: Yes, you need pseudo streaming. I am not too familiar with IIS, but here is some information I found on the subject - http://forums.iis.net/t/1162490.aspx/1

Comment: I think it would be super helpful if the longtail website had current, detailed information on how setup linux and windows servers for psuedo streaming. This information is not easy to find, and although the article you reference talks about an IIS module, I've had no success getting that to work. Ideally, we'll all be on an CDN, but many of us are just getting started with a project and we are in the proof of concept stage, and we can't afford to invest in a CDN or the time it takes to integrate into one.

Comment: Sorry, the documentation I sent you is the only documentation we have on the subject. For JW5, the guide is here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12534/video-delivery-http-pseudo-streaming

Comment: Ok, I replied to that one.