# How to add flash video in C# WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, axshockwaveflash

I want to make an interactive trainer for a BIG program. Instead of just making video tutorials, I was thinking to make the videos in camtasia, and edit them with flash. After the videos are ready, I want to upload them to my server, and the C# application should load the flash videos from my server.

I found the solution of adding flash videos to C# with the axShockwaveFlash control.

I can load videos from youtube for example like:

```
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "https://www.youtube.com/v/N6O2ncUKvlg";
```

But if I have the flash videos to my server like http://mywebsite.com/intro.flv how can I load them ?

I guess I need to set them in a player or something like that.

Another idea would be to just make the videos in camtasia, and export them to "web" directly from camtasia. But still, don't know how to tell the control to load it.

I just want to make this, so that it will be a little harder to download the videos. I know they can be easily downloaded also in this way, but it's more safer than just uploading them to youtube.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618871/setting-up-video-streaming-for-jwplayer

Comment: I don't think that's really what I need. I just want to load flash into my C# winforms application

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-play-flash-in-windows-forms-application-using-C-Sharp/) is an extended article on how to load flash in a WinForms application

In short:

- Add toolbox reference to COM Component Shockwave Flash Object (found in C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash)
- Add control Shockwave Flash Object to Form
- Set property Movie: [control].Movie = "[path]\animation.swf";
- Start movie: [control].Play();

Comment: Thanks. I want to put the video on my server (that's the idea, so that it won't get leaked fast).